# Sorting Elements in Struct Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

I'm trying to sort an array of structs in C - I've been trying to use qsort to do this, however, whenever the `sorterFunction` is called, I get a segmentation fault. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here.

This is the struct I have populated my array with

```
typedef struct Song 
{
    char* title;
    char* artist;
    char* year; 
} Song;
```

These are the sorting function

```
int comparisonFunction(const void *first, const void *second)
{
    Song *songPtr = (Song *)first;
    Song *songPtr2 = (Song *)second;
    return strcmp(songPtr->title,songPtr2->title);
}

    void sorterFunction(Song* songList, int globalCounter)
    {
        Song newGlobalList[1024];
        // the following line is the one that causes segmentation fault     
        qsort(newGlobalList, globalCounter, sizeof(Song), comparisonFunction);
        int count = 0;
        while(count < globalCounter)
        {
            printf("%i Title: %s, Artist: %s, Year: %s\n",count+1,newGlobalList[count].title,newGlobalList[count].artist,newGlobalList[count].year);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume you are actually *initializing* the `newGlobalList` array? But do you even *need* the temporary array? Because with the structure you show then `songList` can't be a linked list, but must be a dynamically allocated array, which means you can use it directly.

Comment: I assume `a` and `b` in the `comparisonFunction` should be `first` and `second`.

Comment: @MarcKhadpe Correct! Was trying to make the code more readable for SO, sorry! :-)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes! You can assume that newGlobalList is already initialized as an array of populated structs, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @unicornication Could you show your initialization code? You should try to simply things with just a two or three element array until you find the bug.

Comment: Then, you *are* calling it with a valid pointer as the first argument? A valid `globalCounter` value? Each `Song` structure in `songList` is properly initialized? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your size of array is `globalCounter`, but not `1024`, as specified above.

Secondly, you are missing initialization of songs structs. Thats why inner pointers `char * title` are invalid. You get segfault because of `strcmp`ing invalid pointers

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I was using qsort incorrectly! :-)